# Chrome extension chrome.devtools.network.getHar() getting incorrect harlogs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to get the harlogs of a page in a chrome extension, and have a background page connected to a devtools page, but chrome.devtools.network.getHar() gets the harlogs of the chrome extension instead of the actual page.

Here's my code:

background.js

```
var respondNetwork;
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function (devToolsConnection) {

    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, respond) {
        respondNetwork = respond;
        if (message.message === 'fetch network') {
            devToolsConnection.postMessage({
                message: 'please fetch network'
            })
        }
    });

    devToolsConnection.onMessage.addListener(function (message, sender, sendResponse) {
        alert(message.message);
        respondNetwork({ "networkLines": message.message });
    });
});
```

devtools.js

```
var backgroundPageConnection = chrome.runtime.connect({
    name: "devtools-page"
});

backgroundPageConnection.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {

    chrome.devtools.network.getHAR(function (result) {
        backgroundPageConnection.postMessage({ message: JSON.stringify(result) })
    });
});
```

Is there a way to get the harlogs of the actual page instead of from the chrome extension?

Comment: devtools should be open for the API to work, also devtools.js should be loaded from a `devtools_page` html declared in manifest.

Comment: Yes, it's loaded from a devtools.html page, and I think the devtools API is working, as it is returning a set of harlogs, just the ones from the chrome extension instead of from the page.